# How to install Android after building source code

Tags: android, android-source, fastboot

I compiled source code referring to http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html and downloaded apt binaries for my Nexus 4g s .I did following after building:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot erase userdata
fastboot erase cache
```

Now, I cannot see anything on my phone. What could be wrong? Wasn't the source I built suitable for my device? But, I am pretty sure I have downloaded correct source code and binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rescue your device back, use fast boot to flash the factory image back.

To check why you have this issue, please check:

1. If you did not see ANYTHING after reboot, your boot.img (contains kernel) is not correct
2. If you just see the boot animation but it goes on forever, your system.img is not correct

You should:

1. Make sure you have download the correct source code and switch to the **correct branch**
2. Make sure you are using the correct build configuration by **lunch** and select **correct product**
3. The AOSP does not contains everything, you have to download or pull out from your old system to get the proprietary binaries.

Comment: I downloaded binaries again and repeated same process after doing "make clobber". It seems fine now. Thanks.